# Extracting field values from emacs org-mode tables

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Delimiter: I am new to emacs.
I am trying to make a function that goes through an org-table and extracts particular values and does some arithmetic on them. The arithmetic is irrelevant to my question but I am having trouble getting field values into a list of integers or floats.

For example, the function

```
(defun print-field-value()
  (interactive)
  (setq list '())
  (unless (org-table-p) (error "Not in an org-table"))
  (goto-char (org-table-begin))
  (org-table-next-field)
  (while (org-table-p)
  (add-to-list 'list (save-excursion (org-table-get-field 1)))
  (forward-line))
  (print list)
)
```

when executed on the table

```
|  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 | -12 |
| 78 | 46 | 00 | 36 | 64 |  98 |
```

produces the output

```
(#(" 78 " 0 4 (fontified t face org-table)) #("  7 " 0 4 (fontified t face org-table)))
```

I have two questions for the community:
1. What are these elements of my list? (what type of objects or those)
2. Is there a way I can just get the integers into a list so I can easily perform some arithmetic on the values?

I am ideally looking for a simple way to do this without making another function that parces what the above function returns and extracts the integers. My intuition (maybe flawed) is that there should be an easier way to do this. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#(" 78 " 0 4 (fontified t face org-table))` is a string, in C it would just be noted `" 78 "`. Next, you don't need to print to return a result : putting `list` instead of `print list` was enough in your code.

If you want to discover any mode in emacs, use the fact that all its functions have the same prefix. Here, run `describe-function` `org-table-` and press TAB twice to get the list of all functions that work on org tables. You will then see the promising function `org-table-analyze`, and read its documentation. This way you would probably have come up with the following :

```
(defun get-field-values ()
  (unless (org-table-p) (error "Not in an org-table"))
  (org-table-analyze)
  (mapcar
   (lambda (i)
     (mapcar (lambda (j) (string-to-number (org-table-get i j)))
         (number-sequence 1 org-table-current-ncol)))
   (number-sequence 1 (1- (length org-table-dlines)))))
```

It will give you the matrix of fields, as a list of list of numbers. Mind this function is not interactive, you run it with `M-:`

Comment: As instructed I changed "print list" to "list" but on my machine, this change produced no output when I called the function within the table in my example. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: I will output in M-: but not in M-x. That's the difference between printing and returning (as in C, java or other programming languages). Did you try get-field-values ?

Comment: You must run those functions with M-: where you will type their names surrounded by parentheses. For example (get-field-values)

Comment: When I tried get-field-values nothing happened. I think I may be overstating how much I know about lisp/emacs. I have the aforementioned functions defined between #+begin_src elisp ... #+end_src blocks within an org document. I go to the end of the definition and compile using C-c C-c. Then I move the cursor to a table within the same org file and with my (original) function would type M-x print-field-value and out would come the original strings in the Message Buffer. When you mentioned M-: , I (perhaps foolishly) assumed that meant use M-: instead of M-x when in the table.

Comment: So I just used the parentheses and your function worked great, thank you very much for what was I am sure a noobie tip.